# Get diagonal elements from tf.matmul(tf.transpose(A), A) in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a matrix `A` with several columns, and I need to compute the self dot products, i.e. `tf.matmul(A[:,i]), A[:,i], transpose_a=True)` where `i` indexes columns of `A`. One way is to just compute `tf.matmul(A,A, transpose_a=True)` and extract the diagonal, but this involves a lot of superfluous multiplication (all non-diagonal results are discarded, and the non-diagonal results are most of the results for any matrix larger than 2 x 2). Another way is to do something like

```
out = []
for i in range(tf.shape(A)[1]):
    out.append(tf.matmul((A[:,i],A[:,i],transpose_a=True))
```

and then collect `out` into a `tf.Tensor`. But it seems like this is a fairly common computation, so I would expect a function to exist for it (i.e. computing squared norms of weight vectors).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a little bit of linear algebra and you have your solution:
[image]

Which means that you need to do: `tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(A), axis=0)`

Answer (score 1):

You can multiply the matrix by itself elementwise and then sum along axis 0.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.InteractiveSession()

A = tf.reshape(tf.range(12), (3, 4))
tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(A, 2), axis=0).eval()
```

returns

```
array([ 80, 107, 140, 179], dtype=int32)
```